# data structures for efficient/easy implementation of finite volume method for 2D Poisson equation

Tags: finite-volume, poisson, mesh, data-structures

My question is about implementation alone.

- Consider a square domain with regular square, cell centred finite
  volumes.  This is for the multiscale finite volume method (Jenny and Lunati)
- I need to  solve the Poisson equation on each cell of the "dual mesh", i.e.,
  the mesh constructed by joining centroids of each cell. (the dual mesh will look like a translation of the original mesh; 4 cells of the dual mesh make up one cell of primary mesh)
- I will need to use this to construct the "transmissibilities" for each cell of the primary mesh.

My question is:

1. What kind of date structure should I use that will help me go from primary to dual mesh easily
2. I am confused what I shld store, the coordinates of the cell centres, or the locations of the faces ?
3. How do I store the data that will tell me which 4 dual cells make up a given primary cell ?

It seems to me I will need to do a kind of "assembly" for my transmissibility matrix as I visit each dual cell and solve a local Poisson problem.

Comment: Is the domain partitioned into a fully structured tensor-product mesh? If yes, then all the neighbor-relations can be trivially computed on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the work by Jenny and Lunati, so this answer might be wrong.  But if I understand correctly, the geometry you want can be generated in a few lines using PyClaw; see [this notebook](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/ketch/1a7888d1fcc37209b260).  This figure shows the primary and dual grids:

[image: Grid]

You can also use mapped grids, and ghost cells are automatically generated if you need them:

[image: mapped_grid]

If either of those is what you're looking for, I can post all the necessary code here inline (it's in the notebook linked above).

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider implementing the algebraic MSFV instead? The implementation complexity is a lot less. Details can be found in the paper "An operator formulation of the multiscale finite-volume method with correction function" by Lunati, 2009.